# Transpose SQL select based on values

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

Given table:

```
create table test(obj varchar(99), prop varchar(99), val varchar(99));

insert into test (obj , prop , val ) values ('this', 'type A', 'foo');
insert into test (obj , prop , val ) values ('this', 'type B', 'bar');
insert into test (obj , prop , val ) values ('this', 'type C', 'asd');
insert into test (obj , prop , val ) values ('that', 'type B', 'buz');
insert into test (obj , prop , val ) values ('that', 'type A', 'qwe');
```

How can I select following:

```
| obj | type A | type B | type C|
  this  foo      bar      asd
  that  qwe      buz      NULL
```

This is not a duplicate of "pivot all rows to cols" questions; difference here is condition - value can go to several columns, based on type.

Comment: Which dbms are you using?

Comment: In general, any particular SQL query will always produce a result set with a particular "shape" - the number of columns, their *names* and data types are fixed. Probably have to dynamically construct the query, and the facilities for doing that vary between database systems. So please [edit] and add a suitable tag, as the [tag:sql] tag suggests.

Comment: Edited to answer questions above. More than 2 types, MS SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
select obj, [type A], [type B], [type C]
from test
pivot (max(val) for prop in ([type A], [type B], [type C])) B
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/e969e/4)